# BigQuery "copy table" not working for small tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to copy a BigQuery table using the API from one table to the other in the same dataset. 
While copying big tables seems to work just fine, copying small tables with a limited number of rows (1-10) I noticed that the destination table comes out empty (created but 0 rows).
I get the same results using the API and the BigQuery management console.

The issue is replicated for any table in any dataset I have. Looks like a bug or a designed behavior.

Could not find any "minimum lines" directive in the docs.. am I missing something?

EDIT:
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4UM3.jpg)

Original table: video_content_events with 2 rows

Copy table: copy111 with 0 rows

Comment: Have you tried to open a support ticket with Google and ask their assistance? Doesn't look as designated behaviour to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are you populating the small tables? Are you perchance using streaming insert (bq insert from the command line tool, tabledata.insertAll method)? If so, per the documentation, data can take up to 90 minutes to be copyable/exportable:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability

I won't get super detailed, but the reason is that our copy and export operations are optimized to work on materialized files. Data within our streaming buffers are stored in a completely different system, and thus aren't picked up until the buffers are flushed into the traditional storage mechanism. That said, we are working on removing the copy/export delay.

If you aren't using streaming insert to populate the table, then definitely contact support/file a bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/).

Comment: I'm using the tabledata.insertAll method from the API ... that explains a lot. I tried it now after the 2 rows table was untouched for the night and it did copy it as expected. Does it mean that if I have a big table (1m rows) and just before the copy is running I get 1 row inserted, the last row will not be included in the new table?

Comment: Yep. The last row won't be copied. You can (at the cost of a query) "select *" into a destination table (be sure to allow large results and disable flattening), which will have everything -- streamed data is fully visible to queries and tabledata.list. Otherwise, per the documentation, perform a tables.get (every few minutes) until the "streamingBuffer" section disappears (up to 90 minutes), at which point copy should get all the rows.

Comment: This delay still present? Today did a copy (with overwrite) to another dataset and basically some tables became empty after this copy (in destination dataset)

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum records limit to copy the table within the same dataset or over a different dataset. This applies both for the API and the BigQuery UI. I just replicated your scenario of creating a new table with just 2 records and I was able to successfully copy the table to another table using UI.

[Attaching screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVQ7D.png)

Comment: Updated my question with my screenshots... Just tried it again after I saw yours.. still does not work :\

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy to a timestamp partitioned table. I messed up the timestamp, and 1000 x current timestamp. Guess it is beyond BigQuery's max partition range. Despite copy job success, no data is actually loaded to the destination table.